# Jmeter - time shift a date by 12 months

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario, where the time needs to be shifted by 12 months.

`${__timeShift(dd/MM/YYYY,,P365D,,)}` doesn't helps. It isn't flexible. Depending on leap years, the number of days could change.

Could someone help me with an accurate solution.

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) and use Groovy's [TimeCategory](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html) class like:

```
${__groovy(import groovy.time.TimeCategory; def now = new Date(); use(TimeCategory) { def nowPlusOneYear = now + 1.year; return nowPlusOneYear.format('dd/MM/YYYY')},)}
```

[image]

More information: [Creating and Testing Dates in JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-and-testing-dates-in-jmeter-learn-how)